# Why doesn't the Linguistic Data Consortium release its data sets free of charge?

Tags: annotated-data

The [Linguistic Data Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_Data_Consortium) often sell data sets for a high price.

According to the [Linguistic Data Consortium Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_Data_Consortium)

> The LDC was founded in 1992 with a grant from the Advanced Research Projects Agency (DARPA), and is partly supported by grant IRI-9528587 from the Information and Intelligent Systems division of the National Science Foundation.

so it sounds like most / all of its funding comes from the tax payers. Why doesn't the Linguistic Data Consortium release its data sets free of charge?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about linguistics, it's about politics, involving linguists.

Comment: It is partly supported by those grants. It is partly supported by charging fees, which vary by how big your organization is. US federal funding pays for a very small proportion of such ongoing projects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a complaint about access and funding, not linguistics at all.

Comment: @jlawler No judgment from me, I am simply curious, you're welcome to post your comment as answer.

Comment: I tend to think that the question is on-topic. jlawler was quite informative about the general state of affairs for large-scale academic projects. It may turn out that someone from LDC sees this question -- they'd probably write a more specific answer. The question is specific enough about the business of linguistics to be asked here rather than on politics.se or academia.se.

Comment: Also I guess many linguistic or natural language processing students or researchers wondered about it at some point, since many famous NLP data sets are hosted by LDC. It's not like LDC were some obscure organization.