# Benchmark data sets for negation detection systems

Tags: computational-linguistics, datasets

I am looking for data sets that I could use to train and benchmark negation detection systems.

Comment: Negation detection is a good idea in principle -- like a universal translator -- but it has similar problems in practice. [Negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a **really** complicated matter, and overt negative quantifiers or predicates don't begin to exhaust the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Some (all?) datasets from the [Automatic Content Extraction (ACE) Program](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/collaborations/past-projects/ace)

From [Linguistic Data Consortium. "ACE (Automatic Content Extraction) English annotation guidelines for entities." (2005).](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/sites/www.ldc.upenn.edu/files/english-entities-guidelines-v5.6.6.pdf):

[image]

Unfortunately, it is [not available free of charge](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14358/2680).